# PHP Prepared Statement Result Array Not Finding Correct Value

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli, prepared-statement

the PHP below works fine in instances of insertion, but with a select query of bound parameters, not much luck has come through with the json reading.  The application I'm creating now always returns false with the if statement evaluating the number of rows.  I have a feeling the issue truly lies with the scope of the mysqli_stmt_store_result($query).  The login credentials of the user do not work when attempting to login even though they are correct.  Please let me know if more information is needed.  The database connection is fine.

```
//parameter checking
$username = safe(stripslashes(trim($_POST['username'])));
$mypassword=hash('sha256', $salt.$_POST['password']);

//sanitize input parameters
function safe($value)
{
    global $db;

    $secureString = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $value);

   return $secureString;
} 

//query check
$query= mysqli_prepare($db, "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username =? AND password =? AND block_status < 1");
//$result=mysqli_query($db,$query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query,'ss',$username,$mypassword);

mysqli_stmt_execute($query);

/* store result */
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($query);

$query2="UPDATE Users SET last_login=NOW() WHERE username ='" . $username . "' AND password = '" . $mypassword . "'";
$result2=mysqli_query($db,$query2);


//if match found, create an array of data and json_encode it
if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($query)>0)
{


    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    $response=array(

        'logged'=>true,
        'name'=>$row['name'],
        'email'=>$row['email']
    );

    echo json_encode($response);
}
else
{
    $response=array(

        'logged'=>false,
        'message'=>'Invalid credentials or your access has been revoked'
    );
    echo json_encode($response);
}

    /* free result */
    mysqli_stmt_free_result($query);

    /* close statement */
    mysqli_stmt_close($query);

    mysqli_close($db);

?>
```

Comment: You don't need to use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` if you're using parameter binding

Comment: Thanks, I will update that once I figure out this scripting error.

Comment: @Phil for some very strange reason the OP is using prepared statement for the first query but not for the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php), you should be using `mysql_stmt_store_result()` **before** calling `mysql_stmt_num_rows()`.

Also, you should use parameter binding for your `UPDATE` query, but only after you've confirmed a successful login.

I highly recommend PDO over MySQLi. The API is much cleaner and easier to understand. Here's how I would do it...

```
// assuming your user table has a primary key `id`
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT `id`, `name`, `email` FROM `Users` WHERE `password` = ? AND `username` = ? AND block_status < 1');
$stmt->execute(array($passwordHash, $username));
$user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($user !== false) {
    $response = array('logged' => true) + $row;

    $update = $db->prepare('UPDATE `Users` SET `last_login` = NOW() WHERE `id` = ?');
    $update->execute(array($row['id']));
} else {
    $response = array(
        'logged'  => false,
        'message' => 'Invalid credentials or your access has been revoked'
    );
}

$stmt->closeCursor();

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
exit;
```

Comment: I've tried putting it before, but then I get a json error.  Should I even bother with parameter binding on select queries?

Comment: @Klinetel absolutely. I would always bind user input. There's really no other sane option. Also, what JSON error are you getting?

Comment: Ok. The application I'm feeding this into says unable to parse JSON string line 1...  But, when I move the mysqli_stmt_store_result to the num rows if statement, the error goes away but the if statement will only evaluate to false.

Comment: @Klinetel I've updated my answer using [`bind_result()`](http://www.php.net/manual/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) and [`fetch()`](http://www.php.net/manual/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php). You may be able to use `fetch_array()` but I'm not really big on MySQLi so don't know exactly how to implement that one. My only other suggestion is to use PDO, the API is *much* cleaner

Comment: I assume the downvote is due to the pseudo-code example. I've updated it to a real one

Comment: People will downvote anything...  I'll check it out after work today. Please use procedural mysqli to keep my code consistent.

Comment: This may be necessary:  http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php

Comment: Do you have to explicitly select the table ID in the query with PDO?

Comment: You could use `SELECT *` but I always prefer to be explicit in selecting the data to return.